# Find my Bitcoin please

Tags: bitcoin-core

I purchased $100 worth of bitcoin when it was first introduced. Maybe back in 07/08/09.   I never done anything with it  I have no idea even what computer system I was using at that time, or even what old email addresses I used. Is there any hope for recovery.  Is there a way to use an IP address and using any keywords.  It might have even been on an old AOL account.  Any one have any thoughts other then I’m a loser.  Thanks

Comment: It can't be 07 or 08. There is a possibility it was in 2009 , but do you remember where you purchased the Bitcoin? Most exchanges popped up after 2010. Honestly, I can't even name one place/exchange that sold bitcoin in 2009.

Answer (score 1):

What wallet did you use at the time? Probably the standard wallet so you would have to look for a wallet.dat file.

So grab every old harddrive and computer you can find and use a custom search program like search everything (voidtools . com) to search for wallet.dat file.

If you found it: Make a backup copy first (or two or three..)

Then on a different computer, download bitcoin core and sync the blockchain. After sync has finished, replace the wallet.dat file bitcoin-core created automatically with the old one you've found.
After that core will rescan the blockchain and after that you are good to go.

Good Luck!

(Since you might be a multi millionaire in case you find that coins I would appreciate a tip ^^ 1HcgC2jpqXZhkia7sxriE6S435qqR8zKqq)